# Array elements can only be selected using an integer index

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a List Group Members action to get the members of a security group >> then I am trying to build semicolon separated string for the members emails inside a compose action, as follow:-

[image: johnjohn123_1-1698880893372.png]

but i got this error;-

***'The template language expression 'join(outputs('List_group_members_2')?['body/value']?['mail'],';')' cannot be evaluated because property 'mail' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an integer index.***

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do in your way.
To do:

- declare a new variable of type `array`

[image: variable array]

- use `Apply to each` to iterate of each users part of the group
- check if the user has an mail, if true, append it to the array
- use `compose` and `join` if you want to join the values with a comma:

`join(variables('Emails'), ',')`

You can also use a *string variable* and concatenate emails with a comma on each iteration.

Workflow:
[image: worklow]